# how a Fibonacci heap increases the efficiency of the Prim's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, priority-queue, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm, fibonacci-heap

I know Prim's algorithm and  Fibonacci heap but my question is:
how a Fibonacci heap increases the efficiency of the algorithm over an array list based minimum priority queue implementation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Prim's algorithm with a Fibonacci heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825518/how-to-implement-prims-algorithm-with-a-fibonacci-heap)

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826037/208527

Comment: Before you get too excited about Fibonacci heap, see the last paragraph of the introduction to [Pairing heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap): Researchers " concluded that pairing heaps are often faster in practice than array-based binary heaps and d-ary heaps, and almost always faster in practice than other pointer-based heaps, including data structures like Fibonacci heaps that are theoretically more efficient." Pairing heap is easier to implement, and in real world use it's faster than Fibonacci heap.